# How to Refresh Excel every half hour and Automatically Save on exit

Tags: excel, vba, automation, refresh

I curently have an excel file that has data being imported into it.
The way it is setup now is that on open it refreshes and then on close it auto saves.
I would like to Open the file, have it refresh every 30min and save every time it completes a refresh, as well as sill save the file on close.

My current code is:

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

I dont know any VBA so i appreciate all your help.

Comment: Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196165(v=office.15).aspx)